# Cómo cambiar comillas francesas (Guillemets) por comillas dobles (Inverted commas) con "enquote" en Latex

Tags: latex

Estoy usando la instrucción `\enquote{texto a citar}` del paquete *csquotes*, y la citación me sale con comillas francesas de esta forma:

```
«texto a citar»
```

¿Cómo hago para que Xelatex utilice comillas dobles y me muestre la cita de esta forma?:

```
"texto a citar"
```

Mi entorno de trabajo es el siguiente:

```
documentclass[11pt]{book}
% Packages
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{D:/Oscar/Github_SKR/Latex_SKR/PryPrPre/ProyectoPra/My Library.bib}
\usepackage{svg, pdfpages}
\usepackage{caption, sectsty}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}

Agradecería alguna respuesta para lograr citar con comillas dobles \enquote{texto a citar}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

A mi me funciono con esto:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
% packages
\usepackage[english]{babel} % esta linea y la de debajo nos colocan las comillas dobles
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\begin{document}
 \enquote{Esta es una cita en bloque}
\end{document}
```

Decime si te funciona, estoy usando un compilador online. La informacion la saque de [StackExchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52351/quote-marks-are-backwards-using-texmaker-pdflatex)